# Ajuda em espaçamento entre EditText

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Não consigo dar uma espacamento entre as EditTexts no meu projeto. a quantidade de EditTExts são geradas conforme a quantidade informada pelo usuário, ou seja, foi programada no Código Java.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Caso alguma resposta tenha resolvido seu problema seria interessante marcá-la como respondida

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como você já usa o `LayoutParams` ao adicionar a nova `view`, fica mais simples pra explicar.

Antes de chamar o `layout.addView` lá na ultima linha, você deve declarar o LayoutParams antes (como já está fazendo no `layout.addView`, mas precisa ser antes pra poder definir as margens), logo após você define as margens dele (que deseja que seu `editText` tenha) e depois é só jogar ele ao adicionar a `view`

```
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll);

    EditText[] editT = new EditText[6];

    for(int i=0; i < 6; i++){
        editT[i] = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
        editT[i].setHint("Periodo" + (i+1));
        editT[i].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        ll.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(300, 100); //LinearLayout ou o tipo do seu ViewGroup
        layoutParams.setMargins(0,15,0,0); //Define as margins em left, top, right e bottom respectivamente
        ll.addView(editT[i], layoutParams); //Adiciona a view e informa o LayoutParams que ela irá usar (que contém as margens e o tamanho da view)
    }
```

Há outro modo também de definir o `layoutParams` da sua `view`, a última linha do código acima você poderia trocar por essas:

```
editT[i].setLayoutParams(layoutParams); //Define o LayoutParams da view
ll.addView(editT[i]); //Adiciona somente a view, já que já foi definido o LayoutParams
```

Eu testei aqui no Android Studio agorinha e funcionou tudo ok.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (p instanceof LinearLayout.LayoutParams) {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)p;
        if (_default) lp.setMargins(mc.oml, mc.omt, mc.omr, mc.omb);
        else lp.setMargins(mc.ml, mc.mt, mc.mr, mc.mb);
        this.setLayoutParams(lp);
    }
```

Porque this.getLayoutParams (); retorna um ViewGroup.LayoutParams, que não possui atributos topMargin, bottomMargin, leftMargin, RightMargin. A instância do mc que você vê é apenas um MarginContainer que contém margens de compensação (-3dp) e (oml, omr, omt, omb) e as margens originais (ml, mr, mt, mb).

Ref.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12728255/in-android-how-do-i-set-margins-in-dp-programmatically